# cast(date as timestamp) comparison is incorrect

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

When I'm executing this comparison, it is giving incorrect result.

```
select case when cast('06-JAN-17 12.48.14.243000000 PM' as timestamp) > 
            cast('06-JAN-17 08.08.57.000000000 PM' as timestamp) then 1 else 0 end from dual
```

the result is '0' instead of '1'. Could someone help me what is wrong in this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [TO_TIMESTAMP](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions229.htm#SQLRF06142) when you like to cast a string to TIMESTAMP properly.

```
when TO_TIMESTAMP('06-JAN-17 12.48.14.243000000 PM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF PM') > 
            TO_TIMESTAMP('06-JAN-17 08.08.57.000000000 PM', 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF PM') 
  then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score -1):

You first need to convert your text literal to a date before you cast it to a timestamp. I show you an example:

```
select case when cast(to_date('06-01-17 12:48:14', 'DD-MM-YY HH:MI:SS') as timestamp) > cast(to_date('06-01-17 08:08:57', 'DD-MM-YY HH:MI:SS') as timestamp) then 1 else 0 end from dual
```

---

This resturns 1.
Just change my literal by yours and the passing date format and your result will work as well.

Comment: Casting a `DATE` into `TIMESTAMP` does not make sense in this scope. For given values like `06-JAN-17 12.48.14.243000000 PM` it will even fail because `DATE` does not support fractional seconds.